# What is the R value of Kapok Fiber

Tags: insulation

I'm attempting to find a green and cheap insulation for the roof of a school bus conversion I am building. Kapok is easily sourced for me as it literally grows on trees.

The dimensions of the roof are approximately 40' by 8.5'.

But what is the R-value of Kapok?
Are there other cons I should be aware of?

Comment: Generally anything that grows is a bad idea for insulation.  Like the horsehair insulation of old, it will interact very, very badly with water -- it will invite mold growth.  And relevant to you *it will retain water*, which means rusting out the bus body.

Comment: Also, since it is a conversion (to a place people are when not in motion), consider **flammability** - it could spread fire too fast to escape.  A common source of fire is whatever you use to heat the space.   Another is **poisonous smoke** which could hurt your escape chances by incapacitating you or doing long-term health damage.  Aviation people pay very close attention to this. Granted organic things are less likely to be toxic, but far more likely to be flammable.

Comment: Most insulation is cheap, usually the expense is down to fitting it...

Comment: as @Harper states, flammability is a problem, but can be helped by treatment, e.g. applying borates. Kapok is cellulose, so see this reference: https://insulationinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/FG_MW_vs_Cellulose_Final.pdf

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That resource and clarification was super helpful. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Harper states, flammability is a problem, but can be helped by treatment, e.g. applying borates. Kapok is cellulose, so see [this reference](https://insulationinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/FG_MW_vs_Cellulose_Final.pdf). However, the amount of fire-retardant used is ~20% by weight.

That said, kapok was the standard filler (in separate compartments) for life vests for many years.

According the the link, the R-value of cellulose is between 3.2 and 3.8 per inch.

Answer (score 1):

Scientific paper on thermophysical properties of kapok

[Research Journal of Applied Sciences, Engineering and Technology](http://maxwellsci.com/print/rjaset/v2-143-148.pdf)

Comment: You should put the relevant info in your answer, as links can suffer from link-rot...